# Running some actions before bind() method

Tags: java, tapestry

I wonder, is any convenient and appropriate way to describe in `Tapestry5` in `AppModule` some actions, which should be invoked **before** `bind()` method will run?

Of course, it is possible, to include such actions inside `bind()` method in top of method block. But it seems, that must be some other possibility for this.

BTW, `@Startup` is not eligible way for this, due in my case it uses already started services, but I need to some actions before services will be bound.

Comment: Maybe you can use service builder methods? (http://tapestry.apache.org/tapestry-ioc-modules.html)

Comment: May be you don't need to ?? Is it ok to share what precisely are you trying to do ?

Comment: I think, I need. Sorry, but let me decide what architecture I want by my self.

Comment: "let me decide what architecture I want by my self" is quite arrogant and unproductive. We'd rather help you solve the right problem rather than the wrong one, and without more details, there's no way to tell what path you are on.

Comment: @HowardM.LewisShip Well, you are right, my comment was quite arrogant. I apologize for that. But actually I really need such architecture of my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outside of Tawus' answer; no, there's nothing you can do, short of a static code block (which is standard Java, not Tapestry related).

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes I have found myself using an unnamed static block in the module class - mostly to initialize legacy services that my Tapestry services depend on. Something like:

```
public final class MyModule {

    static {
        // early set-up here
    }

    public static void bind(ServiceBinder binder) {
        // binding here
    }
}
```

This seems to improve the module code readability a bit, but at the same time could be somewhat difficult to set up for unit testing.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a Tapestry web application, you can extend [`TapestryFilter`](http://tapestry.apache.org/current/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/TapestryFilter.html) and have the initialization step there. Look into the source code of TapestryFilter for inspiration. Also see [TapestryAppInitializer](http://tapestry.apache.org/current/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/internal/TapestryAppInitializer.html)

Comment: Thanks, but it is not, what I actually ask. I wonder, how to do it correctly inside `AppModule`...